# need help converting feet inches into inches in excel formulas

Tags: excel-formula

i'm using excel for my madden league and i want to convert the feet-inch designation into straight inches becuase it makes things alot easier for me    . if you could help me design a formulat that would calculate those data points into inches so i can autosum and then average that would be amazing!
6'0''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'4''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'5''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    6'4''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    5'11''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'3''
    5'11''
    6'4''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'3''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'3''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'5''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'4''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'4''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    5'11''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    5'11''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'6''
    6'0''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'0''
    6'4''
    6'4''
    6'2''
    6'3''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'0''
    6'3''
    6'0''
    6'1''
    6'3''
    6'3''
    6'3''
    6'4''
    6'2''
    6'1''
    6'2''
    6'2''
    5'11''

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("'",A1)-1)*12 + MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("'",A1)-2)
```

[image]

Comment: @Rob Cole, Mrig has -2 at the end of his formula because your data use TWO single quotes instead of one double quote.  His formula works perfectly.  But you will need to change to -1 if you are using one double quote.  Just a heads up.